Where should the PRIVATE folder be placed?
I have a Drupal 11 website and I want the images to be in a private folder. I have read the Drupal documentation but I am not sure if my private folder is in the right location.
This is the tree of my server. Is the "private" folder in the right place?
../private
../web

This seems odd. You have a Drupal 11 install but are not using the recommended composer project. If you are asking for the best place for the private folder, the answer would be outside of the /web folder of the recommended composer project. If you put it inside the published folder, you depend on the autogenerated .htaccess files to protect this and the vendor folder.

@4uk4 I have the same question as this post https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2014-05-25/why-file-directory-is-at-systemfiles

Are you showing that file field on a page that anonymous users can see? If so, that's working as designed.

Strictly speaking, there isn't really a "right" place for the private files folder. As long as it's protected from public access, that's all that's needed.
Of course to help with this, it's generally recommended that the folder be stored outside of the docroot (which in most standard configurations means it's protected from public access via a browser, by default).
So where you've placed it should be fine. If you want extra peace of mind, double-check that your webserver configuration doesn't inadvertently make that folder publicly accessible for some reason.

Thanks, so I'll leave it there, however I don't understand how to use the private directory. I've updated the question

It sounds like you probably haven’t configured it, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/file/overview#s-private-file-system-settings-in-drupal-8. Make the settings.php change, clear the cache, and the private files options will appear

It works after clearing the cache but I don't understand the usefulness of the private folder. Indeed if I open an image in a private window it is displayed and search engines can reference it. I want the image to be accessible only to authenticated users and not to be referenced in search engines.

That's what the private files folder will do. Note however that this only works for files attached to Drupal entities through field references, with the field storage set to private. Creating the folder, and simply dropping images into it, will not work, as Drupal needs to register them, so that it can then serve them, checking access before doing so.

Also note that the access permissions of the file are  inherited from the permissions of the parent entity it is attached to. So if the file is private, but the node it is attached to is open to anonymous users, the file is essentially public since anyone can access it.
